# Highlight Incoming Mails That Were Forwarded to Me in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules, mail-rule

I am facing with a stupid issue on my part: whenever I receive a message, I always stop at the (lengthy) signature of the sender, and never check whether there is anything after it. This is especially an issue, when they are forwarding a message and start talking about it without specifically stating "underneath" or "in forwarded mail" and I go along with whatever I think the context actually is. It would be clear if there is no context to connect it with, but often a mail is a continuation of a topic in some form, like feedback on a project or a prior issue. Some senders also not using Outlook in English, so "Fwd:" and "Re:" might not appear in the subject, though it might not even help in my case, as I don't read it, and it is possible to remove them—though no one removed them yet.

While obviously I could ask the sender to always clearly point out whenever they are forwarded a mail, I can't really make sure everyone does that, and it may even come through rude for some. I have set up a formatting rule to highlight forwarded mails in my inbox, so when I open the mail, I know I should take extra care to read further the first signature, but it depends on the subject starting in a particular text. Is there any specific way that detects and signals that the mail continues after the signature? I am thinking along the line of listing all the words in the condition the body of the mail may hold that indicates a repeating mail header that is language independent, maybe even a regular expression, or an add-in making a more elaborate and directed check of the mail body that indicates a lengthy "signature" and warns if it is potentially followed by any other text or even remove the signature for viewing.

Comment: One (very imprecise) approach might be to have some VBA which counts the total number of lines that state "Sent: xxxx" and then flags a warning if that total is more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not protect from yourself.

Make a two stage approach.

Make a folder "todo"  and file these mails in todo.

When you have gone back to review and read the whole thing, file the mail where you want it filed.  That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an alert when you receive the new mail. It is also a mail flow rule. You can configure that by Outlook Client.
Here are the detailed steps:
1.Navigate to **File ->Manage rules and alerts**
2.Select **New rules** then **click Display mail from someone in the New Item Alert Window**
3.Then you can make up a rules ,such as specific words in the subject or in the title.